# Simple approach to using TypeScript to specify all properties of object are of type string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following ACTIONS object

```
const ACTIONS = {
  FETCH_ERROR: 'API fetch error',
  ACTIVATE_QUIZ: 'activate quiz',
  ACTIVATE_RESULTS: 'activate results',
  CHECK_ANSWER: 'check current answer',
  NEXT_QUESTION: 'go to next question',
  DEACTIVATE_QUIZ: 'deactivate quiz',
  UPDATE_DATA: 'update all the data',
  RESET_STATE: 'reset all the state'
}
```

And I want to specify that only properties of type string can be allowed in it. I have no idea of how to this, that's the reason I'm not proposing an attempt.

Comment: That should be the inferred type of the object right now. https://i.imgur.com/oFog37D.png [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggYQCoEkDyA5AyjAvDAbwCgYYAxAUSQQAkB9CgJUbUYC4YByOABRRgBmAUyjAAFjCEAnKSCmcANCXjIUANThIKdAIoBVFAC0OnAIbAoASwBupqEJgBHAK6WAXouWJUGrXUYUWHoAMkhYJuZWtvYwUkIQzgA2UBCepLQUCADSdHDYAOpMJuJCwADWMMDOMkJgsKaQAO7SaTAYFAAaSLp6gaiYJgDmIDBQI2BCAB6wLvFW4K0AIhTe6pra+kYmACZCkTZ2Di7urXo8i+t0F0hwJs4ADtuHMKaJiaNiDk9Qpq0BWFQ6FgbloTHEICIXm8Pg5oIdOEQAL5AA)

Comment: Yes, so.. I shouldn't specify it by using TS? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: `const ACTIONS: Record<string, string> = {`

Comment: @OriDrori that works, thanks.. Could you explain it? or send me a link where I could read more about that. I don't understand it :S

Comment: You don't have to do anything. TS will automatically infer the type. If that type is not accurate *then* you need to specify the correct one.

Comment: @OriDrori you'll loose the keys inferrenece.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, but I can still add a property with type number and it won't throw errors. So I think it would be nice to have a type specified

Comment: @AlekseyL. what do you mean by that?

Comment: No, you cannot add numeric properties without errors: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggYQCoEkDyA5AyjAvDAbwCgYYAxAUSQQAkB9CgJUbUYC4YByOABRRgBmAUyjAAFjCEAnKSCmcANCXjIUANThIKdAIoBVFAC0OnAIbAoASwBupqEJgBHAK6WAXouWJUGrXUYUWHoAMkhYJuZWtvYwUkIQzgA2UBCepLQUCADSdHDYAOpMJuJCwADWMMDOMkJgsKaQAO7SaTAYFAAaSLp6gaiYJgDmIDBQI2BCAB6wLvFW4K0AIhTe6pra+kYmACZCkTZ2Di7urXo8i+t0F0hwJs4ADtuHMKaJiaNiDk9Qpq0BWFQ6FgbloTHEICIXm8Pg5oIdOEQAL5EIirTBYAB0E0aWSEAE88DAACwAJgA3KjVOiMZRqPQmCxGITSWSgA)

Comment: `ACTIONS.foo` will be allowed (non existing key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const ACTIONS: { [key: string]: string } = {
  FETCH_ERROR: 'API fetch error',
  ACTIVATE_QUIZ: 'activate quiz',
  ACTIVATE_RESULTS: 'activate results',
  CHECK_ANSWER: 'check current answer',
  NEXT_QUESTION: 'go to next question',
  DEACTIVATE_QUIZ: 'deactivate quiz',
  UPDATE_DATA: 'update all the data',
  RESET_STATE: 'reset all the state'
}
```

or use [`Record<keys, type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) utility type:

```
const ACTIONS: Record<string, string> = {
  FETCH_ERROR: 'API fetch error',
  ACTIVATE_QUIZ: 'activate quiz',
  ACTIVATE_RESULTS: 'activate results',
  CHECK_ANSWER: 'check current answer',
  NEXT_QUESTION: 'go to next question',
  DEACTIVATE_QUIZ: 'deactivate quiz',
  UPDATE_DATA: 'update all the data',
  RESET_STATE: 'reset all the state'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It would be very helpful if you could expand with some explanation.

Comment: The first approach is the standard TS syntax when specifying the type of the object key and the corresponding value, thus `[key: string]: string`. The second one, `Record<keys, type>` is a utility type provided by TS (looks cleaner than the first one, but works just the same). Check the link I added in the answer to learn more about TS utility types.